# Request: link to see bounty events ("revisions") even if question has not been edited

Tags: feature-request, questions, bounties, revisions-list

The times when a bounty is placed and when it is awarded are apparently [important enough to be part of the revision history of a question](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/29262).  However, for questions like [this one](//stackoverflow.com/q/5888987) which have not been edited, the information is not visible from the question page (although you can access it by [constructing the revisions URL manually](//stackoverflow.com/posts/5888987/revisions)).

Can we get a link to the "revision history" even when there are no edits, or some other way to see the bounty info without manually typing in the `/posts/[id]/revisions` URL? It's strange to show the timing of bounty events **only** when the edit history is non-empty.

Comment: You can still get to it via: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5888987/revisions and http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9186141/revisions

Comment: @Flexo I didn't know that, but that still makes one wonder why there's no link to those pages if they indeed exist.

Comment: I know the duplicate was asked later, but it does seem to have got more useful responses and attention :/